# Allow only one CDocument to be opened in an MFC MDI app

Tags: c++, mfc

As the question says, I am trying to only allow one document at a time in an MFC MDI app. For many (unrelated) reasons I am not using an SDI document template. Many places comment on doing this, but I cannot find out how. The closest is the suggestion in this link: http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/06d5cebffaeefeae.htm but it doesn't work with CWinAppEx - the document is closed, even if the user cancels the File Open dialog. Further, use of the MRU list or toolbar buttons by-passes this suggestion.

Any help much appreciated!

---

```
BOOL CMyDoc::closeDocument()
{
    if (!SaveModified())
    {
        // User has vetoed the close, return error
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // OK to close
        OnCloseDocument();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And in CMyApp:

```
void CMyApp::OnFileOpen()
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = CMyDoc::GetDoc();
    if (pDoc != NULL && pDoc->closeDocument())
        // user has vetoed the close - can't create new one
        return;
    // no document currently open, or we succesfully closed it    

    CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen();
}


void CMyApp::OnFileNew()
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = CVATDoc::GetDoc();
    if (pDoc != NULL && pDoc->closeDocument())
        // user has vetoed the close - can't create new one
        return;
    // no document currently open, or we succesfully closed it
    CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen();
}
```

---

While this might have worked in older version of MFC, it seems not to work now (VS2013). The document is closed before the user has selected (or cancelled) a new document.

Comment: Can you explain some of the "many reasons" why SDI is not working out for you? Also: please show what you changed where in your wizard generated app.

Comment: I have many views that I'm displaying based off the one document. These are created on the fly and it's far easier to manage, alongside CDockablePanes etc, given the MDI setup. The code is as per the link - I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way, and does not involve hooking into all those functions.  Add some ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI() message map handlers to your application object.  Specifically, ID_FILE_NEW and ID_FILE_OPEN.  When you have an open document, disable the command.  Here's some code.  Not guaranteed to work, but should get you there.

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_NEW, SomeUpdateHandler)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_OPEN, SomeUpdateHandler)

void CMyApp::SomeUpdateHandler(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    POSITION pos = GetFirstDocTemplatePosition();

    CDocTemplate* pTemplate = GetNextDocTemplate(pos);

    POSITION posDoc = pTemplate->GetFirstDocPosition();
    pCmdUI->Enable(posDoc != NULL);
}
```

If you have an open document, then File-New and File-Open will be disabled.  Once you close the document, you can open or create a new one.

Comment: That's a nice solution Joe, and perhaps enforces in the user's mind a bit better that it is a "workspace" type application, similar to VS2013 itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I've got a solution working and think it's useful to explain it. I hope this is useful for someone. I've spent ages stepping through MFC (a good thing to do) and see now why the solution linked to above is no longer a solution in MFC9.

## File Open Commands

### From Most Recently Used list

The call stack is like this:

```
CWinApp::OnOpenRecentFile(UINT nID) // Non-virtual – cannot override
CWinApp::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName) // Virtual – can override in CMyApp
CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName)
CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName, BOOL bAddToMRU)
CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bAddToMRU, BOOL bMakeVisible); // here is the actual creation of the new frame etc
```

So the only place to hook in, is by overriding `OpenDocumentFile` in your `CMyApp` class.

### From a dialog

This is easier - there are multiple places to hook in, but hooking in at the start won't allow the user to have the file open dialog displayed and cancel it, while keeping their existing document open.

```
CMyApp::OnFileOpen(); // override
CWinAppEx::OnFileOpen(); // call base class
CDocManager::OnFileOpen(); // This one is key – in here the File Open dialog is shown
CMyApp::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName) // And here we can hook into the call stack
CWinAppEx::OpenDocumentFile(lpszFileName);
CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName)
CDocManager::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName, BOOL bAddToMRU)
CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bAddToMRU, BOOL bMakeVisible) // here is the actual creation of the new frame etc
```

## File New Command

This one is tricky since there is no hook in once the `OnFileNew` has been called.

```
CMyApp::OnFileNew(); // virtual override
CWinAppEx::OnFileNew(); // base class
CDocManager::OnFileNew(); // this calls the doc template without another hook back into our derived classes
CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bAddToMRU, BOOL bMakeVisible)
```

## Solution

A solution is to derive our own DocTemplate class and re-writing some of the function but this is a big job. A 'hackier' method is the following.

### Opening a file

This hook works for both MRU and dialog commands - see the call stack above. The File Open dialog has already been displayed and file selected. We don't get to here if the File Open dialog is cancelled.

```
CDocument* CMyApp::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszFileName)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = CMyDoc::GetDoc(); // static func that gets pointer to MyDoc
    if (pDoc != NULL && pDoc->closeDocument())
        // user has vetoed the close - can't create new one
        return NULL; // here we prevent opening by by-passing base class call
    return CWinAppEx::OpenDocumentFile(lpszFileName);
}
```

### New file

Here since there is no dialog to cancel, we can hook in right at the start and prevent the new file being created if the user doesn't permit the existing document to be closed.

```
void CMyApp::OnFileNew()
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = CMyDoc::GetDoc();
    if (pDoc != NULL && pDoc->closeDocument())
        // user has vetoed the close - can't create new one
        return;
    // no document currently open, or we succesfully closed it
    CWinAppEx::OnFileNew();
}
```

Finally, the `closeDocument()` function is as per the link above:

```
BOOL CMyDoc::closeDocument()
{
    if (!SaveModified())
    {
        // User has vetoed the close, return error
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        // OK to close
        OnCloseDocument();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are no objections, or better suggestions, I'll accept this as the answer soon.